# What is the purpose for each of the eosio.* system accounts?

Tags: smart-contract, accounts, permissions, system-accounts

There are several eosio.* accounts - also referred to as `system` accounts -  described in the [bios sequence tutorial](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Tutorial-Bios-Boot-Sequence):

```
eosio.bpay
eosio.msig
eosio.names
eosio.ram
eosio.ramfee
eosio.saving
eosio.stake
eosio.token
eosio.vpay
```

It is mentioned there that `eosio.msig` is a privileged account

What is the purpose of each of these accounts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bios sequence tutorial (Deprecated Wiki)](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Tutorial-Bios-Boot-Sequence/f4d63486ca815c1245e181edfed77e6a99eeb28e) explain these well - eosio.token, eosio.msig.

The remaining accounts are described below.

- all RAM trading fees sent from user to eosio.ramfee
- all proceeds from selling RAM sent from eosio.ram
- all staked tokens sent to eosio.stake
- all unstaked tokens sent from eosio.stake
- all auction proceeds sent to eosio.names
- unallocated inflation sent to eosio.saving
- producer block pay sent to eosio.bpay
- producer vote pay sent to eosio.vpay

I refer to the following link.
https://steemit.com/eos/@slavix/block-one-releases-eosio-dawn-4-2

Answer (score 1):

**This article goes into detail.**

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence

---

Here are some that I found:

> The eosio.token contract. This contract enables you to create, issue,
>   transfer, and get information about tokens.
>
> The msig contract enables and simplifies defining and managing
>   permission levels and performing multi-signature actions.
>
> The eosio.system contract contract provides the actions for pretty
>   much all token-based operational behavior. Prior to installing the
>   system contract, actions are done independent of accounting. Once the
>   system contract is enabled, actions now have an economic element to
>   them. Resources (cpu, network, memory) must be paid for. Likewise, new
>   accounts must be paid for. The system contract enables tokens to be
>   staked and unstaked, resources to be purchased, potential producers to
>   be registered and subsequently voted on, producer rewards to be
>   claimed, privileges and limits to be set, and more.